# Canonical Invariance in the Context of Thermodynamics of the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, mathematical-physics, harmonic-oscillator, lie-algebra

I'm reading a paper titled "[Thermodynamical analysis of a quantum heat engine based on harmonic oscillators](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.94.012119)". Section $C$, is dealing with a subject called "Canonical invariance". The system under investigation is a quantum harmonic oscillator. I copy a subsection of the contents of this section in order to be able to ask my question. The section reads:

> For the harmonic system a finite set of Hermitian operators
> $\hat{X_k}$ can be defined so their general evolution can be written
> in the closed form,
>
> $\frac{d}{dt}\hat{X}_j(t)=\sum_{k=1}^K a_{jk}(t)\hat{X_k}(t)\quad$
> with $a_{jk} \in  \mathbb{R}\quad (\star)$
>
> which can be written in matrix notation as
>
> $\frac{d}{dt}\underline{\hat{X}}(t) = A(t)\underline{\hat{X}}(t).$
>
> This property follows from the fact that the operators form a closed
> Lie algebra and that the system exhibits canonical invariance. In the
> Schrödinger picture the property called canonical invariance is when
> an initially canonical form for the density matrix,
> $\hat{\rho}=(1/Z)exp(\sum_k \beta_k \hat{X}_k)$, retains this form at
> all instants of time. The density operator $\hat{\rho}$ is completely
> parametrized by the time dependence of the coefficients $\beta_k(t)$.

I have a few questions:

1- Does the equation ($\star$) imply that the Hilbert space is spanned by the operators $\hat{X}_k$?

2- How one can prove that having a closed Lie algebra along with the condition which is called "canonical invariance", leads to the equation ($\star$)?

3- Is the concept of canonical invariance here related to the kind of canonical invariance that we have in classical mechanics (preservation of symplectic structure under canonical transformations)? If so, what does it have to do with the ability to express the state as a Gibbs state like they did here? What is the idea behind all this?

The article doesn't refer to any other articles for the mentioned content and there is no further explanation about this in the appendix. So, I assume that there might be a trivial point that I'm missing. Any guidance and reference recommendations is highly appreciated.